# "Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzb" how to resolve this issue for adMob?

Tags: android, admob

I am using Android Studio 3.3 (latest version). What should be the issue here in the duplication of libraries? and these are the latest steps shown in the Google AdMob website.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:stfalcon-imageviewer:0.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'

    //UI
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    implementation 'xyz.belvi.mobilevision:barcodescanner:2.0.3'

    //adMob
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

solved it by downgrading the version of com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads to the version used for other google play services ..